# requirejs optimizer creates code that does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, require, requirejs

I am using "define" in my project. My js code woks when I don't use the optimzer. When I run the optimizer all files are included  se below

```
require(["jquery", "modals", "registermodule", "bootstrap", "personsmodule", "datemodule",    "./jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min"], function($) {});


C:/Users/pethel/checkout/src/main/webapp/resources/scripts/main-built.js
----------------
C:/Users/pethel/checkout/src/main/webapp/resources/scripts/jquery.js
C:/Users/pethel/checkout/src/main/webapp/resources/scripts/modals.js
C:/Users/pethel/checkout/src/main/webapp/resources/scripts/ajaxmodule.js
C:/Users/pethel/checkout/src/main/webapp/resources/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js
C:/Users/pethel/checkout/src/main/webapp/resources/scripts/datemodule.js
C:/Users/pethel/checkout/src/main/webapp/resources/scripts/validationmodule.js
C:/Users/pethel/checkout/src/main/webapp/resources/scripts/guimodule.js
C:/Users/pethel/checkout/src/main/webapp/resources/scripts/registration_util.js
C:/Users/pethel/checkout/src/main/webapp/resources/scripts/registermodule.js
C:/Users/pethel/checkout/src/main/webapp/resources/scripts/bootstrap.js
C:/Users/pethel/checkout/src/main/webapp/resources/scripts/tablesort.js
C:/Users/pethel/checkout/src/main/webapp/resources/scripts/personsmodule.js
C:/Users/pethel/checkout/src/main/webapp/resources/scripts/main.js
```

When I load my page with the uglified script i get datepicker not defined. How can this happend when the file is included here jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that  jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js isn't AMD module.

Solution 1: Wrap code of jquery-ui to AMD module

Solution 2: remove dependency in your code and include it manually.

There is other solutions how to work with non-AMD dependencies but I don't know how optimizer will work in that cases.

Comment: Soultion 1: That cant be done manually ? I will need something like http://tagneto.blogspot.no/2011/01/jquery-ui-as-amd-modules-for-use-in.html Solution 2: what do you mean bu that. Another <script> tag?

Comment: <script data-main="${homeUrl}resources/scripts/main-built" src="${homeUrl}resources/scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="${homeUrl}resources/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script> This apporach works in chrome but IE still complains about the datepicker.